# Apache Rewrite rule pointing to password protected directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Consider the following structure of a directory, which is served by an apache webserver under the URL `sample.com` :

```
/local/path/index.html
/local/path/.htaccess
/local/path/admin
/local/path/admin/.htaccess
/local/path/admin/projects/project1/index.html
/local/path/admin/projects/project2/index.html
/local/path/admin/projects/project3/index.html
```

Whereas `/local/path/projects` is a symlink pointing to some other directory.
Thus the contents of `/local/path/.htaccess` is basically this rule:

```
Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

The other .htaccess ensures that the admin directory is password protected.

When `http://sample.com` is requested `index.html` is served.
When e.g. `http://sample.com/admin/projects/project1` is requested, the contents of `/local/path/admin/projects/project1/index.html` are served, after the user has entered the correct password.
Requesting `http://sample.com/admin` of course leads to an 404 Error.

My intention is now to to make the address `http://sample.com/admin` serve `/local/path/admin/projects/project1/index.html`. But this should be nor redirection, meaning that e.g. in a browser url-bar the url remains the chosen one. However redirecting to `http://sample.com/admin/` would be ok, if necessary.

---

I tried to enhance the `/local/path/admin/.htaccess` file with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^admin admin/projects/project1
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) admin/projects/project1/$1
```

But the rules seem to have no effect. Is it maybe because it points to a password protected area?

On the other hand, it was not possible to create a rule inside the `admin/.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projects/project1/$1
```

What am I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule inside `/local/path/admin/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ /admin/projects/project1/index.html [L]

RewriteRule ^(?!projects/project1/).+$ /admin/projects/project1/$0 [L,NC]
```

Comment: this works quite well. But what if, project1 contains some more files which are needed by the html. I tried: `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /admin/projects/project1/$1 [L]`  but this does not do it.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment completely but you can try my updated rules in `admin/.htaccess`:

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to give a better look at the documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> When using the rewrite engine in `.htaccess` files the per-directory
>   prefix (that is, the URI path that lead to the directory containing
>   this  `.htaccess` file) is automatically removed for the `RewriteRule`
>   pattern matching and automatically added after any relative (not
>   starting with a slash or protocol name) substitution encounters the
>   end of a rule set. See the [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive for more information
>   regarding what prefix will be added back to relative substitutions.

And again:

> The removed prefix always ends with a slash, meaning the matching
>   occurs against a string which *never* has a leading slash. Therefore, a
>   *Pattern* with *^/* never matches in per-directory context.

So given that the per-directory prefix is automatically removed, you should try your rewrite rules without the `admin` prefix when you are writing `/local/path/admin/.htaccess`.